# Access violation in stack frame 5 at address 0x200005f88 of size 8

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I am facing an error called Access violation in stack frame ..., I tried to solve my problem by boxing my Account but didn't work.

This is github link
https://gitlab.com/toanbt173404/anchor-launchpad/-/blob/master/programs/anchor-launchpad/src/contexts/dever/create_launchpad.rs?ref_type=heads#L9

This is example of transaction error:
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/XcJv1cQgyicdVirqU1BiEvmxmRZLMzqb4asAET9k1RekeB864PWshzJAEGzeuJbN9JrKVUB1Zgr3VwgHrgcztAU?cluster=devnet#ix-1

My instructions

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreatLaunchpad<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub dever: Signer<'info>,
    pub launchpad_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = dever,
        space = LaunchpadAccount::INIT_SPACE,
        seeds = [b"launchpad".as_ref(), &dever.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub launchpad_account: Box<Account<'info, LaunchpadAccount>>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = dever,
        associated_token::mint = launchpad_mint,
        associated_token::authority = launchpad_account
    )]
    pub vault_launchpad: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub config_account: Box<Account<'info, ConfigAccount>>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = dever,
        space = MintConfigAccount::INIT_SPACE,
        seeds = [b"mint_config".as_ref(), &launchpad_mint.key().as_ref(), &dever.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub mint_config_account: Box<Account<'info, MintConfigAccount>>,
    #[account(
        mut,
        associated_token::mint = launchpad_mint,
        associated_token::authority = dever
    )]
    pub dever_token_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

impl<'info> CreatLaunchpad<'info> {
    pub fn create_launchpad_data(
        &mut self,
        bump: &CreatLaunchpadBumps,
        params1: LaunchpadParamsStep1,
        params2: LaunchpadParamsStep2,
        params3: LaunchpadParamsStep3,
    ) -> Result<()> {
        //send creation fee to pool 
        let dever =  &mut self.dever;
        let launchpad_account = &mut self.launchpad_account;
        send_lamports(dever.to_account_info(), launchpad_account.to_account_info(), self.config_account.creation_fee)?;

        let launchpad_account_data = 
        LaunchpadAccount {
            bump: bump.launchpad_account,
            add_fee_un_con : self.config_account.add_fee_un_con,
            dever_address : self.dever.key(),
            is_sale_active: 0,
            creation_fee_option_sol: self.config_account.creation_fee_option_sol,
            total_contributors: 0,
            total_commission: 0,
            time_public_wls: 0,
            total_whitelist: 0,
            total_buyed: 0,
            total_history_refs: 0,
            launchpad_params_step_1: params1,
            launchpad_params_step_2: params2,
            launchpad_params_step_3: params3,
        };
        self.launchpad_account.set_inner(launchpad_account_data);

        self.mint_config_account.set_inner(MintConfigAccount {
            bump: bump.launchpad_account,
            authority: self.dever.key(),
            mint: self.launchpad_mint.key(),
            commission: 0,
        });
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn send_tokens_to_pool(&self, amount_to_sell: u64) -> Result<()> {
        let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
            from: self.dever_token_account.to_account_info(),
            to: self.vault_launchpad.to_account_info(),
            authority: self.dever.to_account_info(),
        };
        transfer(
            CpiContext::new(self.token_program.to_account_info(), cpi_accounts),
            amount_to_sell.into()
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Likely one of your functions is using too much stack space, so you may need to reduce the size of other variables. Keep putting accounts in `Box`es or see if you can break up your functionality over multiple instructions. There's not much else possible at the moment unfortunately