init_if_needed causing "access violation in stack frame 5"
Just like the title says, I am running into issues where i get "failed: Access violation in stack frame 5 at address 0x200005fd8 of size 8" but only when using init_if_needed, without it the code works fine but obviously if the account initialized is already initialized then the transaction fails.
heres an example of the context for the transaction
pub struct CreateSwap<'info> {
    #[account(mut, has_one = owner)]
    pub user_account: Box<Account<'info, UserAccount>>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user_token_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [swap.key().as_ref(), b"swap_token"],
        bump,
        payer = owner,
        token::mint = swap_token_mint,
        token::authority = swap,
    )]
    pub swap_token_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = owner,
        seeds = [b"swap".as_ref(), swap_ref.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = 333
    )]
    pub swap: Box<Account<'info, Swap>>,
    /// CHECK: The `swap_ref` is simply generated for a unique Ref for each swap.
    /// It is safe because it is only for creating a seed.
    pub swap_ref: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub swap_token_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
    pub receive_token_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        seeds = [swap_token_mint.key().as_ref(), b"swap_token"],
        bump,
        payer = owner,
        space = 222
    )]
    pub swap_token_market: Box<Account<'info, Market>>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        seeds = [receive_token_mint.key().as_ref(), b"swap_token"],
        bump,
        payer = owner,
        space = 222
    )]
    pub receive_token_market: Box<Account<'info, Market>>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,
    pub receiving_token_account: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    pub swap_lp_quote: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    pub swap_lp_base: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    pub receive_lp_quote: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    pub receive_lp_base: Box<Account<'info, TokenAccount>>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

To explain a little bit about the program and how it works and what its doing, is its basically just an escrow/peer to peer swap. a user creates the swap account, the tokens are held in the PDA, when another user fulfills to swap the pda transfers to the buyer, and the buyer transfers directly to the seller. there is an option for both fixed rates and floating rates.
in order to handle these floating rates what I do is create PDAs for their markets, that holds their LP accounts (eg if you wanted to swap bonk for wif, it would create a market account for both wif, and bonk, that stores its mint id, raydium pool token account, and raydium pool wrapped solana account.) these accounts are created once for each token, but the intention is to automatically initialize them if they arent already initialized so there is no need to add your own token to the swap.
So to recap, my createSwap context works fine if im using init, but runs into overflow issues if im using init_if_needed.
I have used init_if_needed in the past before without any issues however in that transaction there was 1 init, and 1 init_if_needed, not 1 init, and 2 init_if_needed.
I believe what ill have to do is make a seperate instruction for market creation and then if a market account is not found then bundle the market creation with the swap creation instruction. But im asking here in case anyones had issues with this in the past and knows a work around for it.

This sounds similar to https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/11814/access-violation-in-stack-frame-5-at-address-0x200005f88-of-size-8
